# Cómo realizar movimiento de letras en la consola con JAVA

Tags: java

Buen día, sé que esto NO es una pregunta con código, pero iré directo al grano, me encontré con un ejercicio que se muestre una palabra o letra que se desplace a la izquierda. Investigué y descubrí uno hecho pero en HTML, CSS y JAVASCRIPT https://codepen.io/Run1t/pen/NpqEVP

Cómo podría realizarlo en JAVA, ya que no tengo ni una sola idea, ni he llegado a encontrar tutoriales, vídeos o páginas para guiarme.

El trabajo básicamente es que se mueva la letra o letras hacia la izquierda, pero no sé como hacerlo.

¿Alguien ha podido realizar este ejercicio? Si es así me gustaría que me oriente un poco.

Todo esto lo estoy haciendo en JAVA SE con consola, pero si alguien lo ha hecho en JFrames, mucho mejor.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Eso se puede hacer en consola? Tengo entendido que es de entrada/salida, lo que ves escrito creo que ya no se puede cambiar, otra cosa es que se escriba una nueva línea con las modificaciones, no le veo más solución. Con una GUI, ya es diferente, porque su contenido responde a eventos y se puede interaccionar con el. Saludos.

Comment: También se me entró esa duda amigo @Orici, según tu experiencia crees que esto se puede llevar a cabo ya sea en consola o en GUI?

Comment: En GUI sin se puede modificar el contenido textual, por ejemplo de un *label* sin problemas.

Answer (score 5):

He intentado buscar referencias de como hacer en consola pero te diría que es demasiado complicado, se ha de dibujar las letras y mover cada segundo (que en realizad es dibujarlo otra vez pero cambiando de posición). Si te sirve de respuesta usando una GUI se vuelve mas sencillo, en este caso te pongo un ejemplo de una applet, en este no usa matrices como el ejemplo en Javascript que has puesto en el link, lo único que hace es dibujar lo escrito en x e y posición, y re-dibujarlo cambiando de posición, he comentado un poco para guiar en lo que pueda.

```
public class LedDisply extends Applet implements Runnable {
    private String Pantalla;
    private int PosicX, PosicY, Flag;
    Thread thread;

    // Inicializamos cuando empieza la applet
    public void init()
    {
        Pantalla = "Esto saldra en pantalla";
        PosicX = 100;
        PosicY = 100;
        Flag = 1;

        // Creamos el thread
        thread = new Thread(this, "UnThread");

        // Lo ejecutamos
        thread.start();
    }

    // Actualizamos la x
    public void update()
    {

        PosicX = PosicX + 10 * Flag;
        if (PosicX > 300)
            Flag = -1;
        if (PosicX < 100)
            Flag = 1;
    }

    // Aqui pintamos la pantalla en cada cambio de posicion
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // Hacemos un repaint
            repaint();

            update();
            try {

                //Pausamos 1 seg para que notemos el movimiento
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString(Pantalla, PosicX, PosicY);
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.